# How to mock download attribute of a link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am working on updating an app from Angular 1.2 to Angular 1.4 and in the course, broke some of the karma tests.  Most are easy fixes, however there are a few that I can't get working.  The tests rely on checking if the download attribute is defined to determine how to download the required file.  Before the upgrade, the tests could just set elem.download.  After the upgrade, I can't seem to set download.

Here is how I'm setting up the element for the tests:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = undefined;
```

And then in the code itself, it is a very simple

```
if(link.download !== undefined) {
    //do stuff (this test works)
} else {
    //do other stuff (this test doesn't work)
}
```

When I try to set link.download to undefined, it is still going into the first branch.  If I try to just pass an empty object in, I errors because various properties are undefined, even though the code doesn't seem to be looking at those properties.

I have also tried setting `link.download = null` and changing the if statement to use `typeof`

**TL;DR** How do I set the download attribute to undefined?

Here is a [simple Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0JWdqjX6NyZe5u5WTmLV) with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value set to `download` will be converted to a string value, so your `undefined` is getting converted to `"undefined"` which is why it always passes the `!==` comparison.

**EDIT**

By your comments you want to do feature detection of `download`. So to do that use

```
`download` in createElement('a')
//or
HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('download')
```

Then if you want to force a does not exist test you can just delete `download` from the prototype

```
delete HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.download;
```

Comment: The problem is that when you create the element, download is already set to an empty string, so if I just check for falsy, it will always go to the else

Comment: @lucky.hooligan, then your test isn't setting `download` to a usable value from the time you created the element to the time you test it.

Comment: `download` gets set in the true branch of the if statement.  The code is more to check if the browser supports it.  If the browser doesn't support it, then it won't exist on the element created and we need to use a different method to download the file.  It works fine running in the browsers, but to _test_ the other branch, I need to mock `download`

Comment: @lucky.hooligan, for feature detection you would use `'download' in createElement('a')` or `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty("download")`, to trigger a does not exist test you would delete it from the prototype: `delete HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.download`

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot that you could check for an attribute like that, and I never knew that you could delete the attribute from the prototype.  That works in the plunker, so now I just need to get it to work in the test :)  Can you update your answer and I will mark it as correct?